# Dynamic Paperclip options hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip

How do I pass the options hash dynamically in the code below?

```
class Resource < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :attachable, :polymorphic => true

    has_attached_file :attachment #, paperclip_options from attachable

end


class ItemTypeOne < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :resources, :as => :attachable, :dependent => :destroy

    def paperclip_options
        ITEM_TYPE_ONE_OPTIONS
    end
end

class ItemTypeTwo < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :resources, :as => :attachable, :dependent => :destroy

    def paperclip_options
        ITEM_TYPE_TWO_OPTIONS
    end
end
```

I have two different models (referred to as ItemTypeOne and ItemTypeTwo in the code above). These two models have completely different Paperclip storage options (style, path etc)

Answer (score 0):

I think it would go like this

```
class Resource < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :attachable, :polymorphic => true

    has_attached_file :attachment, attachment_options

    def attachment_options
      attachable.paperclip_options
    end
end
```

I'm running, and didn't test this code.  let me know if it helped.

You probably need to write a class method that inspects the type of the object int he polymorphic relationship, and then pass options based on that type

Comment: Thanks for the response. Didn't work unfortunately: `method_missing': undefined local variable or method `attachment_options' for #<Class:0xb69e208> (NameError)

Comment: and if you put `self.` before the name in the method definition?  Hmm... no, this needs to operate upon the instance, but the reference call is a class-based method.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you're after is possible at the moment.

The problem is `has_attached_file` is being executed in the context of the `Resource` **class**. And the class has no idea which type of `attachable` future instances will have at any given time.

For this to work, that call would need to take and store a lambda (or method name) then evaluate it (or call the method) in the context of the given instance and use the options that call returns. Only then could you have different options depending on the concrete type of the relation.

As far as I know, paperclip does not have this feature.

Comment: Correct, though I can't get the attachment_options method to be called in the first place. If I try something like has_attached_file :attachment, lambda {|attachment| attachment.instance.attachment_options}, (assume attachment_options returns a hash for now) I this error: undefined method `each' for #<Proc:0xb542ecc> (NoMethodError). Seems like I can't substitute the hash with a lambda? I can substitute some of the keys in the hash (e.g :style) with a lambda but looks like I can't substitute the entire hash itself. That's my primary problem now.